# Binding DataGrid to two DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable, dataview

I've two `DataTable` with the exactly same structure, schema and constraints, but with different rows.

What I need is to display these tables into a `DataGrid`, concatenated, i.e. first the rows of the first `DataTable`, then the rows of the second.

I don't want to join, merge, or any operation that creates a new `DataTable` object, since I need that changes on the two originals are shown in the `DataGrid` (and also in the other direction: if the user modify something into the `DataGrid`, I want that the two originals `DataTable` are updated).

So I guess that what I need is a sort of "proxy", like a `DataView` on the two `DataTable`, but I have no idea if this is possible.

Comment: You still need to concatenate them into one object (another table, view, etc.) which is then set as a `DataGrid.ItemsSource`. Relationship doesn't matter.

Comment: @Sinatr but in this way changes on the two original DataTable do not affect  the DataGrid, nor vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

> proxy", like a DataView on the two DataTable,

I would recommend that a vector class entity be created which has all the properties of the columns to be shown. But this class entity will keep a reference to the originating data. Distill the two DataTables into one list of this new object and bind to that list.

To handle changes, have the class adhere to `INotifyPropertyChange` and create a *data manager* which will subscribe to each instance's property change. When the manager detects a change, it pushes the change back to the originating DataTable's row.

```
public class DataVector : INotifyPropertyChange
{
    public DataTable OriginationDataTable { get; set; }
    public int OrininationRow { get; set; }

    // Mirror the properties
    public string Name { get {} { _Name = value; NotifyChange("Name"); }


    // CTORs which help create this object
    public DataVector(DataTable dt, int originatingRow) { ... } 

   ....
}
```

Comment: This may work, but it is not suitable if the names of the columns are known only at runtime, unless you use reflection.. Is it right?

Comment: @WoDoSc Sure one has to know the columns, but frankly why wouldn't one? Who is receiving unknown interfaces from database calls? The scenario is IMHO a one-off.

Comment: actually in my case the number (and the names) of the columns change dynamically, depending on the "instance of the problem" I'm trying to handle. For example each column of my table is a company, and each row a product (or vice-versa), and a cell contains the cost of that product in that company (this is just an example, my situation is slightly different, but I cannot mention it here).